# Stretching with tabular*

Tags: tables

I have found this solution here to stretch the space evenly *between* all colums in a `tabular*` environment:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=33.0]@{}}
\toprule
{$x$} & {$y$} \\
\midrule
1 & 64 \\
2 & 20736 \\
3 & 16777216 \\
4 & 25600000000 \\
5 & 63403380965376 \\
6 & 232218265089212416 \\
7 & 1180591620717411303424 \\
8 & 7958661109946400884391936 \\
9 & 68719476736000000000000000000 \\
10 & 739696442014594807059393047166976 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve that the space remaining is evenly distributed *before the first column*, between all columns and *after the last column*?

**Addendum**

I would like to avoid dummy columns in order to maintain the option to easily copy-paste complex tables into other documents. I tend to use `tabular*` oder `tabularx` if and only if the width of an unstretched `tabular` is close to `\textwidth`. In these cases, it does not look nice, in my opinion, if the stretching occurs only before the first column or only after the last column or only between columns.

(This question may have been asked before, however, I was not successful in searching for a solution.)

Comment: You can add dummy `c` columns at either side, with leading and trailing `&` on each row. But the result won't be pretty.

Comment: @egreg Please see my addendum. Is using dummy columns the only way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\extracolsep` is only added *between* columns, not at the outer sides.

You can add dummy columns at either side, but I find the result suboptimal.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=33.0]
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {$x$} & {$y$} & \\
\midrule
& 1 & 64 & \\
& 2 & 20736 & \\
& 3 & 16777216 & \\
& 4 & 25600000000 & \\
& 5 & 63403380965376 & \\
& 6 & 232218265089212416 & \\
& 7 & 1180591620717411303424 & \\
& 8 & 7958661109946400884391936 & \\
& 9 & 68719476736000000000000000000 & \\
& 10 & 739696442014594807059393047166976 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A table should have its natural width, an exception might be a table having width not so different from the line width. But a two column table should never be stretched anyway.

[image]

In this case the text width is 398.33862pt and the table at natural width is 221.87434pt, a mere 56%.

---

A (semi)automatic solution without dummy columns:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\tabplusbox}
\newlength{\tabpluswd}
\NewEnviron{tabular+}[3][\linewidth]
 {%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \sbox\tabplusbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}#3@{}}\BODY\end{tabular}}%
  \setlength{\tabpluswd}{\dimexpr(#1-\wd\tabplusbox)/\numexpr#2+1\relax}%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabpluswd}}
    #3
    @{\hspace{\tabpluswd}}
  }
  \BODY
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular+}{2}{
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=33.0]
}
\toprule
{$x$} & {$y$} \\
\midrule
1 & 64 \\
2 & 20736 \\
3 & 16777216 \\
4 & 25600000000 \\
5 & 63403380965376 \\
6 & 232218265089212416 \\
7 & 1180591620717411303424 \\
8 & 7958661109946400884391936 \\
9 & 68719476736000000000000000000 \\
10 & 739696442014594807059393047166976 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular+}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You have to pass the number of columns (parsing it from the specifiers could be done, but it would be nasty).

The trick is to measure the natural width of the table, then computing the amount of intercolumn space to insert by subtraction and division by the number of columns plus one. Then we can insert the computed amount of padding on either side and compute the correct value for `\extracolsep`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The 56 % stretching occurs only due to the MWE. In real world (with complex typearea settings I did not want to include in the MWE) we are talking about few percent.

Comment: @Matthias If it's just a few percent, then it's immaterial whether you accumulate the space between columns.

Comment: @Matthias I added a new implementation.